# How can I modify this linear time algorithm?. I am doing window based normalization on pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

> df is pandas dataframe ,
>   min_max_scaling  is a normalizing function [0,1] ,
>   n_steps is  windows size

```
def rolling_normalize(df):
   x_feat = ['feat1','feat2','feat3','feat4']
   y_feat = 'target'
   n_steps = 30
   X, y = list(), list()
   df = df.reset_index(drop=True) 
   for i in range(len(df)):
       end_ix = i + n_steps
       if end_ix > len(df):
           break
       seq_x, seq_y = min_max_scaling(df[x_feat].iloc[i:end_ix]), df[y_feat].iloc[end_ix-1]
       X.append(seq_x)
       y.append(seq_y)
   return X, y
```

Comment: What do you want to change?

Comment: I want to reduce the complexity. May be to Olog(n)